# Can I make my HUD take up less space?

Tags: dota-2

The HUD takes up too much space and, as a result, the game *looks* like it's running 640x480 because of the **huge default HUD** while it's actually running at 1080p. Is there a way to make the HUD smaller?

[image: big hud]

Comment: What's your desktop resolution? And double-check the resolution in-game.

Comment: 1920x1080, the game is running borderless windowed at fullscreen resolution.

Comment: do you mean the zoom level seems to close? that is intended and had a long discussion in the dev dota forums. there were several exploits to change it that i will not mention. the screen itself is not much bigger then the hud. some huds are so tight to the bottom that they give the maximum of vision. if you remove the hud completely it will be a big black rectangle taking up the space instead

Comment: Can you put a screenshot ? I dont get what you mean by running 1080p vs 640*480. Are the resolution in game set properly ?

Comment: Try putting the game in fullscreen mode and check if that helps.

Comment: You could look into buy the MLG hud on the Community Market, it is a bit smaller than the others, but not amazingly small. Dota is just meant to be played with a little "viewport". Plus I'm quite sure the game is made, so that people with higher resolutions see more or less the same as those with lower resolutions. Otherwise it would be unfair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HUD is relatively big compared to other MOBA games such as LoL.
There is no "legal" way to resize the HUD apart from taking a HUD-skin which might be a teensy bit smaller.

It took me a while, but you get used to it.

Comment: It's not too big... what are you talking about?

Comment: The Dota1 HUD took up more screen space than the Dota2 HUD imo.

Answer (score 5):

The HUD in Dota2 is set to a constant size to give everyone a level playing field.
In some games the higher the resolution, the more you can see.  Which in turn gives an advantage to the players with the better tech.

So for competitive/balance reasons, the HUD cannot be re-sized.

Answer (score 0):

You can reclaim some of the pixels the default HUD stole you by using a custom skin.

MLG Stronghold is possibly the leanest one, [have a look here](http://dota2.gamingmedley.com/hud_skins/stronghold/) and see for yourself.

Plus, it's cheap, you can get it on the Steam market for less than 50c.